# Recive CSV by API in Symfony using Postman

Tags: api, symfony, csv, postman

Im using Symfony3 and i have this route:

```
/**
 * Recive a file
 *
 * @Route("/get/file", name="get-file")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function getFileAction (Request $request) {

    foreach($request->files as $key => $uploadedFile) {
        $name = "westSummary".date("Y-m-d")."_".$key.".csv";
        $file = $uploadedFile->move($destiny, $name); //Save the file in server, Where $destiny says.
    }

    return $this->json(array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'code' => 200,
        'data' => $request,
    ));
}
```

And i create a Collection in Postman calling this route and that return the JSON object correctly:
[image: responseBody]

But i cant test if the CSV arrives to the request object.
I have tryed this:
[image: csvtest]

But the Response is the same in both cases

**- How can i send a CSV to and API using POSTMAN?**

Comment: What is the question? The method you posted has no connection to any CSV file posted

Comment: at the end of the post are the questions. I need revice the file by post and i dont know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re trying to do this via the collection runner, this functionality isn’t supported.

That collection runner option relates to the data file you want to use to populate the request variables and not a file upload.

This is a issue being recently discussed on the Postman GitHub account.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3137

To upload a file in the request - You can do this by selecting the `form-data` option in the request body. There is a `text/file` dropdown - By selecting `file` you will get the option to choose one for the request.

[image: File Upload]

One other way that you can achieve this using a collection is by installing [Newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman) and using this to create a script to upload the file during the test run.

Comment: You answered to "How can i send a CSV to and API?", but not "Where can i found the file?"

Comment: "Where can i found the file?" - I don't understand what that even means.

Comment: I understand this "Where can I found the file in the request symfony's side ?" but I'm not the asker ^^

Comment: I can infer what it means but I’d rather the asker of the question be clearer so there is no confusion.

Comment: what are you trying to do with this file server side?

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was looking for. The Tab Vody and tipe file is what i need to do my test.
Well done @DannyDainton